How to generate a worldwide MBTile 0 to 10 zoom without crashing?
What is the best way to process a .MBTile of the entire world with 0-10 zoom and -180, 90 to 180, -90 extent ? I've been having trouble generating a worldwide MB tile from a local folder with over 20gb of jpg tiles on my D: drive. I have used MBUTIL, QTILE, QGIS, to name a few, and all have crashed for various reasons.
MBUTIL and Qtile outputs a blank 1kb .mbtiles files.
QTILE was the most descriptive of its error, as it crashed because multiple threads were attempting to access the data base at the same time.
QGIS crashes after a couple hours.
Many of the tutorials only process a small section of the Earth, but our project requires the whole world. Is there a better process or specific tool for dealing with massive .MBTiles?

I think you will need to provide details, what are your computer specs? Most GIS computers will easily use 32GB of RAM if available to process and many chipsets are muti-thread capable.
